# How can i import media directory in a .py file using from ..media

Tags: django

I need to access files from my media directory that i can read using georinex and iterate over them but i cant seem to access the media directory, i keep getting **invalid syntax error: from ..media**. Kindly help me.

I have tried changing the media url in the root urls.py but it doesn't work and frankly if i were to find an easier way such as from ..media it will very pleasant.
Also i have several different files in the media directory: observation, report, coordinate but am more interested in the observation.

Here's the code am trying to test out:

```py
import georinex as gr
from surveyorportal.models import Files

    def read_rinex_file(self):
        obs = gr.load(self.observation_file.path)
        print(obs)
```

I expect the code to read the file and after which i can implement the iteration

Comment: Is this code a part of your Django project, or separate?

Comment: The code you have posted does not contain "from ..media". Please post the actual relevant code and the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Now that's the bit i want to know how to actually do it. What do you import from ..media

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Import is for Python modules. How - and why - would you import a directory of media files?

Comment: i have created the media root from settings.py and i have uploaded my files. i need to access those files in a similar manner as importing views.py to urls.py but in this particular case it will be the media to the script that i have

Comment: @Reez0 Yes. It is

Answer (score 0):

The following should work within views.py:

```
      import georinex as gr
      from .models import Files

      path = 'E:\\Project\\GWADSpro\\media'

      def read_rinex_file(file_name):
          obs = gr.load(os.path.join(path, file_name))
          file.position_geodetic = obs.position_geodetic
          file.save()
```